# jboss connection pool doesn't handle errors gracefully

Tags: jboss, datasource, jboss5.x

I'm using jboss 5.0.1 with multiple data sources configured.

It seems that on startup, if one of those is configured incorrectly, jboss throws an exception and refuses to start.

I would like to know if it's possible to configure jboss to be resilient to these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the connections in the xml file which holds the connection parameters/mapping. In my case, i am using a microsoft sql server as the datasource, so i have to use the mssql-ds.xml file (inside the server/deploy directory) to specify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>myTestServer</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=MyDB</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
      <user-name>test</user-name>
      <password>abc123</password>
      <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>25</max-pool-size>

      <!-- sql to call when connection is created -->
      <new-connection-sql>select getdate()</new-connection-sql>
      <!-- -->

      <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool
      This will be run before a managed connection is removed from the pool
      for use by a client -->
      <check-valid-connection-sql>select getdate()</check-valid-connection-sql>

   </local-tx-datasource>
 </datasources>
```

This helps control the connections in the pool, and should stop dodgy deadlocks. I'm not entirely sure whether this will test the current transaction level on the connection in question, so if you want to make absolutely sure, you can try: `<check-valid-connection-sql>IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 raiserror ('%s',18,1,'Open Transactions Discovered')</check-valid-connection-sql>`  This will give you an explicit SQLException to handle.

But if you are getting an error on startup, it would be very useful to see what those errors are.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your help. We already have the connection checking in place.  The errors in question come from incorrect username / password.  We want to make sure that jboss continues to start up, and the other connections (which are correctly configured) are set up correctly.